# How are these two functions the same?

Tags: python

Here's the code that Zed Shaw provides in Learning Python the Hard Way:

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"

print "Wait there's not 10 things in that list, let's fix that."

stuff = ten_things.split(' ')
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]

while len(stuff) != 10:
    next_one = more_stuff.pop()
    print "Adding: ", next_one
    stuff.append(next_one)
    print "There's %d items now." % len(stuff)

print "There we go: ", stuff

print "Let's do some things with stuff."

print stuff[1]
print stuff[-1] # whoa! fancy
print stuff.pop()
print ' '.join(stuff) # what? cool!
print '#'.join(stuff[3:5]) # super stellar!
```

Then on one of the study drills, he says:

> 2. Translate these two ways to view the function calls. For example, `' '.join(things)` reads
>      as, “Join `things` with `‘ ‘` between them.” Meanwhile, `join(' ', things)` means, “Call `join`
>      with `‘ ‘` and `things`.” Understand how they are really the same thing.

My problem is, I'm having a tough time seeing how they're the same thing? To my understanding, the first function is saying take whatever is in `things`, and concatenate them with `' '`. But the second function (to my knowledge), is saying call `join`, while using `' '` and `things` as an argument? Sort of the way you would use them when defining a function? I'm pretty lost on this...could you guys could clarify on this?

Comment: Take a look at the specification of the `join` function. What does it do with its two arguments?

Comment: the main thing I wanna know is where this person finds a built-in `join(delim,list)` function....

Comment: I suspect you are looking at an old (and incorrect) version of the book, check out the [same chapter online](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex38.html). Unfortunately I can't seem to find an errata anywhere.

Comment: I have the same question. From what module are you importing a `join` function?  Your question describes standard `string.join()` method, and also a `join(delimiter, list)`, but the code you provide only illustrates the standard `string.join()` method.

Comment: This is all the code that's listed...there's no code stating he imported a join function? I'm not sure if that makes sense...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be precise, `''.join(things)` and `join('',things)` are not necessarily the same. However, `''.join(things)` and `str.join('',things)` *are* the same. The explanation requires some knowledge of how classes work in Python. I'll be glossing over or ignoring a lot of details that are not totally relevant to this discussion.

One might implement some of the built-in string class this way (disclaimer: this is almost certainly *not* how it's actually done).

```
class str:
    def __init__(self, characters):
        self.chars = characters

    def join(self, iterable):
        newString = str()

        for item in iterable:
            newString += item #item is assumed to be a string, and += is defined elsewhere
            newString += self.chars

        newString = newString[-len(self.chars):] #remove the last instance of self.chars

        return newString
```

Okay, notice that the first argument to each function is `self`. This is just by convention, it could be `potatoes` for all Python cares, but the first argument is always the object itself. Python does this so that you can do `''.join(things)` and have it just work. `''` is the string that `self` will be inside the function, and `things` is the iterable.

`''.join(things)` is not the only way to call this function. You can also call it using `str.join('', things)` because it's a method of the class `str`. As before, `self` will be `''` and `iterable` will be `things`.

This is why these two different ways to do the same thing are equivalent: `''.join(things)` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `str.join('', things)`.